# Cannot start first-network on hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to set up the first-network in HL Fabric v1.4.8 samples and I get the following error. I also tried the v1.4.9 binaries and Docker images but is the same issue again.

[image: Error from terminal]

Comment: try "./byfn.sh down" first and after that "./bfyn.sh up"

Comment: I already did that. Also cleared any docker volumes and containers and still, the issue persists.

Comment: It seems to be a issue related to you permissions to execute de docker daemon. The error occurs when you try to install a chaincode, which tries to generate a docker image. And then, you got the issue related to the docker.sock

Answer (score 1):

Try `./byfn.sh down`, most probably it will resolve the issue but sometime you need to stop and remove docker containers manually and clear everything, Note this solution is on for development and testing environment, please don't use on production as it will remove the containers.

Use following commands.

```
docker ps -qa | xargs docker stop

docker rm $(docker ps -aq)

docker rmi $(docker images dev-* -q)

docker network prune 

docker volume prune
```

Then try starting your network, these steps works well for me, hopefully it will resolve your issue.

Comment: I did what you wrote here and the issue still persists. I also did a system prune, and also reset the docker settings to default via the Docker UI. Then pulled the images again using ```curl -sSL <URL from documentation> | bash -s -- 1.4.8 1.4.8 0.4.21``` and tried to start the first-network from the samples and it still has exactly the same issue.

Comment: Then It look issue is with permissions, try to run the following command and restart the system it might resolve the issue, or try to run sudo ./byfn up 

sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER

Comment: "sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER"

or 

"sudo ./byfn up sudo"